# Python local min/max while bin has not changed

Tags: python, numpy

I have a script that produces **bins** using **np.digitize** of values like so:

```
| time | butter | bin |
| :---- | :------ | :--- |
| 2022-07-04 17:33:45+00:00 | 1.041967 | 3 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:00+00:00 | 1.041967 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:15+00:00 | 1.041966 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:30+00:00 | 1.041967 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:45+00:00 | 1.041968 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:00+00:00 | 1.041969 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:15+00:00 | 1.041971 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:30+00:00 | 1.041973 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:45+00:00 | 1.041975 | 4 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:00+00:00 | 1.041977 | 5 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:15+00:00 | 1.041979 | 5 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:30+00:00 | 1.041981 | 5 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:45+00:00 | 1.041983 | 5 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:00+00:00 | 1.041985 | 5 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:15+00:00 | 1.041986 | 6 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:30+00:00 | 1.041987 | 6 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:45+00:00 | 1.041988 | 6 |
| 2022-07-04 17:38:00+00:00 | 1.041989 | 6 |
```

**bins** can **increase/decrease** and they can skip bins.

How can I calculate the local min/max of each bin, so that the result looks like this:

```
| time | butter | bin | min | max |
| :---- | :------ | :--- | :--- | :--- |
| 2022-07-04 17:33:45+00:00 | 1.041967 | 3 | 1.041967 | 1.041967 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:00+00:00 | 1.041968 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:15+00:00 | 1.041966 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:30+00:00 | 1.041967 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:34:45+00:00 | 1.041968 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:00+00:00 | 1.041969 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:15+00:00 | 1.041971 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:30+00:00 | 1.041973 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:35:45+00:00 | 1.041975 | 4 | 1.041966 | 1.041975 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:00+00:00 | 1.041977 | 5 | 1.041977 | 1.041985 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:15+00:00 | 1.041979 | 5 | 1.041977 | 1.041985 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:30+00:00 | 1.041981 | 5 | 1.041977 | 1.041985 |
| 2022-07-04 17:36:45+00:00 | 1.041983 | 5 | 1.041977 | 1.041985 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:00+00:00 | 1.041985 | 5 | 1.041977 | 1.041985 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:15+00:00 | 1.041986 | 6 | 1.041986 | 1.041989 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:30+00:00 | 1.041987 | 6 | 1.041986 | 1.041989 |
| 2022-07-04 17:37:45+00:00 | 1.041988 | 6 | 1.041986 | 1.041989 |
| 2022-07-04 17:38:00+00:00 | 1.041989 | 6 | 1.041986 | 1.041989 |
```

I was trying something with **np.where** and **np.diff** with **np.sign** but I haven't figured it out nor do I feel that's the best way to go about the question.

thank you in advance.

Comment: In your example, why aren't values in the `min` and `max` columns the same for for each row with a given value of `bin`? For example, for rows with bin==5, why aren't min and max always 1.041977, 1.041985 respectively?

Comment: Let me edit it to reflect that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do what your question asks, one using pandas and the other using numpy (**UPDATED** to reflect OP's clarification in comments regarding binning to be on the basis of contiguously grouped `bin` values):

```py
res = df.assign(bin_index = (df.bin != df.bin.shift()).cumsum())

dfAggs = res[['butter', 'bin', 'bin_index']].groupby(['bin', 'bin_index']).agg([min, max])
dfAggs.columns = dfAggs.columns.droplevel()
res = res.join(dfAggs, on=['bin', 'bin_index']).drop(columns='bin_index')
print("", "pandas:", res, sep="\n")

a = df.copy().to_numpy()
print("", "input as numpy 2d array", a, sep="\n")
bin_index = a[:,2:3] != np.concatenate((np.full((1, 1), np.NaN), a[:-1,2:3]), axis = 0)
bin_index = np.cumsum(bin_index)
bins = np.unique(bin_index)
aggs = np.empty((a.shape[0], 2))
for b in bins:
    mask = bin_index==b
    aggs[mask, :] = (a[mask, 1].min(), a[mask, 1].max())
res = np.concatenate((a, aggs), axis=1)
print("", "numpy:", res, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
input as pandas dataframe
                         time    butter  bin
0   2022-07-04 17:33:45+00:00  1.041967    3
1   2022-07-04 17:34:00+00:00  1.041967    4
2   2022-07-04 17:34:15+00:00  1.041966    4
3   2022-07-04 17:34:30+00:00  1.041967    4
4   2022-07-04 17:34:45+00:00  1.041968    4
5   2022-07-04 17:35:00+00:00  1.041969    4
6   2022-07-04 17:35:15+00:00  1.041971    4
7   2022-07-04 17:35:30+00:00  1.041973    4
8   2022-07-04 17:35:45+00:00  1.041975    4
9   2022-07-04 17:36:00+00:00  1.041977    5
10  2022-07-04 17:36:15+00:00  1.041979    5
11  2022-07-04 17:36:30+00:00  1.041981    5
12  2022-07-04 17:36:45+00:00  1.041983    5
13  2022-07-04 17:37:00+00:00  1.041985    5
14  2022-07-04 17:37:15+00:00  1.041986    6
15  2022-07-04 17:37:30+00:00  1.041987    6
16  2022-07-04 17:37:45+00:00  1.041988    6
17  2022-07-04 17:38:00+00:00  1.041989    6
18  2022-07-04 17:38:15+00:00  1.041990    4
19  2022-07-04 17:38:30+00:00  1.041995    4

pandas:
                         time    butter  bin       min       max
0   2022-07-04 17:33:45+00:00  1.041967    3  1.041967  1.041967
1   2022-07-04 17:34:00+00:00  1.041967    4  1.041966  1.041975
2   2022-07-04 17:34:15+00:00  1.041966    4  1.041966  1.041975
3   2022-07-04 17:34:30+00:00  1.041967    4  1.041966  1.041975
4   2022-07-04 17:34:45+00:00  1.041968    4  1.041966  1.041975
5   2022-07-04 17:35:00+00:00  1.041969    4  1.041966  1.041975
6   2022-07-04 17:35:15+00:00  1.041971    4  1.041966  1.041975
7   2022-07-04 17:35:30+00:00  1.041973    4  1.041966  1.041975
8   2022-07-04 17:35:45+00:00  1.041975    4  1.041966  1.041975
9   2022-07-04 17:36:00+00:00  1.041977    5  1.041977  1.041985
10  2022-07-04 17:36:15+00:00  1.041979    5  1.041977  1.041985
11  2022-07-04 17:36:30+00:00  1.041981    5  1.041977  1.041985
12  2022-07-04 17:36:45+00:00  1.041983    5  1.041977  1.041985
13  2022-07-04 17:37:00+00:00  1.041985    5  1.041977  1.041985
14  2022-07-04 17:37:15+00:00  1.041986    6  1.041986  1.041989
15  2022-07-04 17:37:30+00:00  1.041987    6  1.041986  1.041989
16  2022-07-04 17:37:45+00:00  1.041988    6  1.041986  1.041989
17  2022-07-04 17:38:00+00:00  1.041989    6  1.041986  1.041989
18  2022-07-04 17:38:15+00:00  1.041990    4  1.041990  1.041995
19  2022-07-04 17:38:30+00:00  1.041995    4  1.041990  1.041995

input as numpy 2d array
[['2022-07-04 17:33:45+00:00' 1.041967 3]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:00+00:00' 1.041967 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:15+00:00' 1.041966 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:30+00:00' 1.041967 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:45+00:00' 1.041968 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:00+00:00' 1.041969 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:15+00:00' 1.041971 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:30+00:00' 1.041973 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:45+00:00' 1.041975 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:00+00:00' 1.041977 5]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:15+00:00' 1.041979 5]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:30+00:00' 1.041981 5]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:45+00:00' 1.041983 5]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:00+00:00' 1.041985 5]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:15+00:00' 1.041986 6]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:30+00:00' 1.041987 6]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:45+00:00' 1.041988 6]
 ['2022-07-04 17:38:00+00:00' 1.041989 6]
 ['2022-07-04 17:38:15+00:00' 1.04199 4]
 ['2022-07-04 17:38:30+00:00' 1.041995 4]]

numpy:
[['2022-07-04 17:33:45+00:00' 1.041967 3 1.041967 1.041967]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:00+00:00' 1.041967 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:15+00:00' 1.041966 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:30+00:00' 1.041967 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:34:45+00:00' 1.041968 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:00+00:00' 1.041969 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:15+00:00' 1.041971 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:30+00:00' 1.041973 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:35:45+00:00' 1.041975 4 1.041966 1.041975]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:00+00:00' 1.041977 5 1.041977 1.041985]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:15+00:00' 1.041979 5 1.041977 1.041985]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:30+00:00' 1.041981 5 1.041977 1.041985]
 ['2022-07-04 17:36:45+00:00' 1.041983 5 1.041977 1.041985]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:00+00:00' 1.041985 5 1.041977 1.041985]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:15+00:00' 1.041986 6 1.041986 1.041989]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:30+00:00' 1.041987 6 1.041986 1.041989]
 ['2022-07-04 17:37:45+00:00' 1.041988 6 1.041986 1.041989]
 ['2022-07-04 17:38:00+00:00' 1.041989 6 1.041986 1.041989]
 ['2022-07-04 17:38:15+00:00' 1.04199 4 1.04199 1.041995]
 ['2022-07-04 17:38:30+00:00' 1.041995 4 1.04199 1.041995]]
```

Pandas explanation:

- Create `bin_index` column which detects changes in `bin` and increments an id value for each such row
- Use `DataFrame.groupby()` to perform the aggregation (`min`, `max`) based on `bin_index`
- Use `DataFrame.join()` (with preprocessing of the aggregation dataframe `aggs` to remove the level of its MultiIndex named `butter`) to add `min` and `max` columns to the original dataframe.

Numpy explanation:

- Create `bin_index` array which detects changes in `bin` and increments an id value for each such row
- Prepare `aggs` as an array with shape `a.shape[0], 2` for receiving `min` and `max` columns for the corresponding `bin` value in the input array `a`
- Use a boolean mask for each unique `bin` value in `bin_index` to perform aggregation on the corresponding rows of the `butter` column of `a` and to place these two values in the columns of `aggs` for these same rows
- Use `numpy.concatenate()` to glue `a` and `aggs` together horizontally.

Comment: Does this change if bins can repeat (such as bins fluxing over time bin:1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,3)? From the looks of the answers, the aggregate methods would seek all bin #'s and min/max them (all bin 3's or bin 2's, etc.).

When I said "local bin" I was hoping for min/max to be for the local bin 2 [or bin 3 or bin 4 or etc.] so that when the next time bin 3 comes up, it's min/max will only be amongst it's contiguous self and not be aware of the last time the same numbered bin occurred.

Comment: See updated answer based on the clarification in your comment.